# Inconsistent NSDateFormatter result for identical string format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Why does this conversion work some of the time and not others?
When it doesn't work, eDate is null. The original conversion fails.. yet the formats between a working & a non-working date string look identical.
I tried adding an extra "d" in both formatters for dd instead of d. That didn't fix the issue

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];        
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM d hh:mm:ss Z yyyy"];
NSDate *eDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[responceDictionary objectForKey: @"created_at"]];
NSLog(@"original string: %@", [responceDictionary objectForKey: @"created_at"]);

NSDateFormatter *shortFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[shortFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM d hh:mm"];
 NSString *todayString = [shortFormatter stringFromDate:eDate];
 NSLog(@"todayString: %@", todayString);


    2011-05-12 11:01:52.768 Application[1707:207] original string: Wed May 11 19:30:57   +0000 2011
2011-05-12 11:01:52.769 Application[1707:207] todayString: (null)
2011-05-12 11:01:52.770 Application[1707:207] original string: Tue May 10 18:45:01 +0000     2011
2011-05-12 11:01:52.770 Application[1707:207] todayString: (null)
2011-05-12 11:01:52.771 Application[1707:207] original string: Tue May 10 02:24:48 +0000     2011
2011-05-12 11:01:52.771 Application[1707:207] todayString: Mon May 9 09:24
2011-05-12 11:01:52.772 Application[1707:207] original string: Tue May 10 01:05:05 +0000     2011
2011-05-12 11:01:52.772 Application[1707:207] todayString: Mon May 9 08:05
2011-05-12 11:01:52.773 Application[1707:207] original string: Mon May 09 17:38:14 +0000     2011
2011-05-12 11:01:52.774 Application[1707:207] todayString: (null)
2011-05-12 11:01:52.774 Application[1707:207] original string: Fri May 06 12:36:30 +0000     2011
2011-05-12 11:01:52.775 Application[1707:207] todayString: Thu May 5 07:36
2011-05-12 11:01:52.775 Application[1707:207] original string: Fri May 06 12:08:58 +0000     2011
2011-05-12 11:01:52.776 Application[1707:207] todayString: Thu May 5 07:08
2011-05-12 11:01:52.777 Application[1707:207] original string: Fri May 06 11:56:44 +0000     2011
2011-05-12 11:01:52.778 Application[1707:207] todayString: Fri May 6 06:56
2011-05-12 11:01:52.778 Application[1707:207] original string: Thu May 05 22:17:48 +0000     2011
2011-05-12 11:01:52.779 Application[1707:207] todayString: (null)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `HH` instead of `hh` in your dateformat.

The [unicode date format specification](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) states that `h` means hour in 12 (1-12) hour format and `H` is the hour in 24 (0-23) hour format.

The NSDateFormatter can't create a date because 22 (as in your last example) is beyond the limit of 12 hours.